# How to speed up the recovery of mqtt subscription messages after disconnected network reconnection

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, iot, paho

I have a project code in python which need to server send mqtt message to the device, It needs to solve the problem of device and cloud server application operation and information synchronization. I found that [paho.mqtt](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/)!'s Client function has a parameter `Client(client_id="", clean_session=True)` to restore the unconnected subscription to receive the message sent during the offline. But what I found in my experiments is that the longer you disconnect, the longer it takes you to recover, and the slower your message will be.

I would very appreciate it if you guys can suggest me some advice to speed up recovery or any related references about Cloud-Device application operation and information synchronization.

I have written test disconnection recovery

Cloud

```
client = mqtt.Client(client_id='Server',clean_session=False)
client.enable_logger(logger)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT,60)
client.subscribe(topic="Cloud/#",qos=2)
client.loop_forever()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic = msg.topic
    payload = msg.payload.decode('utf-8')
    print(topic)
    print(payload)
    pattern_create = 'Cloud/create'
    pattern_delete = 'Cloud/delete'
    pattern_modify = 'Cloud/modify'
    pattern_connect = 'Cloud/connect'
    if re.match(pattern_create, topic):
        pub("Device/create","create",MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
    elif re.match(pattern_delete, topic):
        pub("Device/delete","delete",MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
    elif re.match(pattern_modify, topic):
        pub("Device/modify","modify",MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
    elif re.match(pattern_connect, topic):
        print('connected')
        pub("Device/connect","connected",MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
```

Device

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    info = msg.payload.decode('utf-8')
    print("##################info=",info)

def wait_to_handle("Device/#", mqtt_host, mqtt_port):
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="wait_to_handle", clean_session=False)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(mqtt_host,mqtt_port,60)
    client.subscribe(topic=topics,qos=2)
    client.loop_forever()

def send_data_func():
    client = mqtt.Client('SendToCloud',clean_session=False)
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.connect(MQTT_IP, MQTT_PORT , 60)
    client.loop_start()
    count = 0
    while 1:
        print(count)
        client.publish('Cloud/count',str(count),2)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

device result

```
...
much Device sent message
...
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
18666
18667
18668
wait handle : Connected with result code 0
##################info= create
##################info= delete
##################info= modify
##################info= create
##################info= delete
##################info= modify
##################info= create
##################info= delete
##################info= modify
##################info= create
##################info= delete
##################info= modify
18669
18670
18671
18672
18673
18674
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
Device sent message
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, using the persistent session by disabling the `clean_session` flag maintains all of the active subscriptions, such that the client need not re-subscribe, and queues up messages (only QoS 1 or QoS 2) if the client temporarily lost connection and reconnected.

The broker will queue up as many messages as it is configured to, which may be in the thousands -- hencewhy the time to recover is proportional to the time of disconnect.

Your options are:

- Set `clean_session` flag to `true`, which would disable all queueing of missed messages but also require you to re-subscribe to topics of interest.
- Keep `clean_session` flag as `false` to maintain your subscriptions, but the publisher to your topics must publish with QoS of 0 to bypass the queueing

  - Additionally, the publisher can set `retained` flag set to `true` on published messages, which will make the broker hold onto the *latest* message on that topic and send it to the client upon re-connect
- Set `clean_session` flag to `true`, but make sure the producer publishes with `retained` flag set to `true`, which will make the broker hold onto the *latest* message on that topic and send it to the client upon re-connect but any QoS will be supported
- Configure the broker to queue up fewer missed messages